# OS X 10.4 - Microsoft keyboard multimedia keys stopped working

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I have a Mac Mini running OS X 10.4.  I've had a Microsoft wireless keyboard and mouse combo working with this machine for a year or two.  Recently the multimedia keys on the keyboard have stopped working.

I've checked the settings under "Microsoft Keyboard" in System Preferences and everything seems to be configured correctly.  I can't think of anything that has changed recently that might have caused this problem (except perhaps the upgrade to iTunes 9?).

The keyboard is a "Microsoft Wireless Multimedia Keyboard 1.1" according to the sticker on the bottom.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I've plugged the keyboard into my laptop running Windows XP and the multimedia keys work fine there so the hardware is not defective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed the latest version of IntelliType Pro from [the Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/support/default.mspx) and, after rebooting, the keys are working again now.  Not sure what caused them to stop working in the first place.